# getting the entire data in redis from redisTemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis

I am relatively new to redis .
I am designing an rest API, to get the entire data set in the redis db.

I used the below code to get all the keys

public Map getAllRedisData() {

```
    Map<Object, Object> map  = new HashMap<>();
    Set<byte[]> keys = redisService.getTemplate().getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("*".getBytes());
    Iterator<byte[]> it = keys.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        byte[] data = (byte[])it.next();
       // String key = new String(data,0,data.length);
        Object key = null;
        try {
            key = getObjectFromByteArray(data);
            System.out.println(key);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
    return map;
}

private Object getObjectFromByteArray(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        return in.readObject();
    } 
}
```

I was able to get all the keys, but wasnt able to retrieve the value for all the keys. Below is the approach 
            "Object value = redisService.getTemplate().opsForValue().get("");"

I guess this is because some keys are of different datatypes.

Let me know if I have to modify/change my approach.

Answer (score 1):

First **keys** should not be used in production. Instead you can use **[scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan)** command.

When you have the key you can call the redis **[type](http://redis.io/commands/type)** command, to retrieve the DataType for the object.

```
DataType -> NONE, STRING, LIST, SET, ZSET, HASH
```

Then you can call the right function to get the data

On large data set this could take a while. Are you sure that you rest api need to get all data into the redis? You can use a pattern with scan to only retrieve the data you really need.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't test it, but try this

```
    try {
        Object value = getObjectFromByteArray(redisService.getTemplate().getConnectionFactory().getConnection().get(data));
        key = getObjectFromByteArray(data);
        System.out.println(key);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```